# Linking posts together with Advanced Custom Fields "both ways"

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields

This is a bit specific, but someone might be able to give a simple explanation if such a thing is possible, so here it is:

I have two custom post types, let's say "Fruits" and "Contries". I want to link "Fruit" posts to "Country" posts and vica versa, which is simple, since using the "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin, I can easily choose post objects (even from other post types) as post meta.

Now the hard part - is there a way to do it "both ways" at once, so the administrator of the site won't have to link twice - "Apples" to "Germany" in the "Germany" post, and "Germany" to "Apples" in the "Apples" post.

For example I can let the user link let's say only "Fruits" to a single "Country" (under the "Country" post) then when I configure my query, I have to tell WordPress to check whether the current "Fruit" queried is chosen as a post object under any post of a different post type ("Countries"), and if it is, list the "Country" posts. I could do that, but at first glance that looks like a bit of an overkill to loop through all the posts in a post type to find out if the current post is linked there.

Any neater/more elegant ideas for this is appreciated. Thank you, cheers!

Comment: To do this you can create a new custom post type e.g. "RelationFruitCountry" and 2 fields in this post type : "fruit" and "coutry". The only thing to test is if its possible to restrain this fields to not have twice the relation "apples" and "germany".

Comment: Yes, they call this "bidirectional relationships" - it's a bit of a manual plugin-writing process but not too complicated. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/bidirectional-relationships/

Comment: Thank you, it's a bit late, so I'm going to study this tomorrow, but at first glance I already see that this is what I was looking for. Would you please reply in the form of an answer so I can accept it?